# Core Data Entity findFirst returns different entity every time, despite the fact there is only one of them

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, restkit

I have a Core Data Model consisting of a Trail that has-many Locations. I am also using RestKit. My code to get the trail looks like this:

```
Trail *trail = [Trail findFirst];
```

My problem is that this returns a different Trail every time. Three successive calls to [Trail findFirst] return:

```
<Trail: 0xf489c70> (entity: Trail; id: 0xf489a60 <x-coredata://77BCA7AD-4C71-437D-8A7C-C047B8E64567/Trail/p1> ; data: <fault>)

<Trail: 0xf476ca0> (entity: Trail; id: 0xf489110 <x-coredata://77BCA7AD-4C71-437D-8A7C-C047B8E64567/Trail/p1> ; data: <fault>)

<Trail: 0xf48c660> (entity: Trail; id: 0xf48c430 <x-coredata://77BCA7AD-4C71-437D-8A7C-C047B8E64567/Trail/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

If I do [Trail allObjects] I see a single Trail item which will be returned the next time I call [Trail findFirst]. If I do [Trail allObjects] again I see a different trail object which will be returned the next time I call [Trail first];

This is bending my mind. How can CoreData be returning a different entity each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong ID. The important one is `x-coredata://77BCA7AD-4C71-437D-8A7C-C047B8E64567/Trail/p1`, all of which show the same number.

The ID you're looking at is the address of the object(s). They *are* different objects but they point to the same underlying Core Data object.

Think of a hypothetical number object. I create one and I put the number 1 in it. I create another number object and put a 1 in that one too. The objects are equal (both contain 1) but they not the same (different objects with different addresses).